# ¿Cómo evitar que texto dentro de inputs tengan transparencia?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

saludos, tengo este codigo

```
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
opacity: 0.102;
```

que me permite que el formulario sea transparente ya que de fondo hay una imagen y un gradiente colocado de esta forma

```
background:url('dirección de imagen'),gradiente;
```

y se genera el efecto de deseado, el problema es que el texto dentro de los inputs en el formulario también se vuelven transparente y es difícil verlo, pueden ayudarme?

Comment: el form esta dentro de un div,, el div tiene la imagen y el gradiente. entonces a form le aplico la opacidad para que se pueda ver el fondo

Comment: Recuerda que si alguna de las respuestas recibidas ha solucionado tu problema se espera que la marques como ["aceptada"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías solucionarlo así:

- Crea un `pseudo-elemento` para crear un `layer` con el color de fondo y la transparencia.

Ejemplo:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1500/1000');
}
form {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
form:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.102;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
form label {
  position: relative;
}
form input {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Nombre: <input/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    Apellido: <input/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    E-mail: <input/>
  </label><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si no he entendido mal tu pregunta, puedes utilizar un selector para los input dentro del formulario. Por ejemplo, si tu formulario usa la clase cFormulario, podrías utilizar la siguiente declaración en css:

```
form.cFormulario input[type=text]{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Adicionalmente, quizás te interese redondear un poco los input text o incluir algún borde para que el contraste con el fondo sea mayor.

Espero haberte ayudado. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Este método no funciona, [mira esta demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6c55mLc8/)

Comment: Hola Marcos, no termino de entender por qué dices que no funciona... "el problema es que el texto dentro de los inputs en el formulario también se vuelven transparente y es difícil verlo". Una opción es hacer los input text visibles... Si lo que quiere Michel es mantener la transparencia en el input pero no en el texto quizás debiera haber sido más específico en la pregunta.

Comment: Yo entendí que el formulario tiene `opacity: 0.102`, y que esto provoca que el texto dentro de los `input`s se vea transparente. ¿Podrías crear un `sinppet` donde se vea que tu solución funciona?

Comment: Hola José, quizas no supe formular bien la pregunta, lo que necesito es que se vea el texto dentro del input

Comment: No hay problema Michel, la solución que porta Marcos parece que sí se ajusta a lo que pides. Marcos gracias por tu fiddle puntualizando :)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se añade `opacity` a un elemento, todos sus hijos heredan esa opacidad. Puedes darle la transparencia que deseas al formulario y al `input` especificando su `background-color` con `rgba`.

Código:

```css
form,input {
 background-color: rgba(222, 215, 215, 0);            
}
input{
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(222, 215, 215, 0.38);
}
div{
 border: 2px solid black; 
 background-image: url(
  "https://www.solofondos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/fondo-celeste-oscuro-6269.jpg"
 );
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div>
  <label>Nombre: <input/></label><br/>
  <label>Apellido: <input/></label><br/>
  <label>E-mail: <input/></label><br/>
 </div>
</form>
```